# Combination of arrays in Matlab

Tags: matlab, combinations, permutation

I have a problem on a part of a program and I would appreciate some help.

My main objective is to use all possible pairs in two arrays. With some help i managed to get this

```
A = nchoosek(0:15, 2)
arr1 = A(:,1);
arr2 = A(:,2);
Result = arr1.*arr2 + arr1.^2 + arr2.^2;
```

I want to use all the combinations in arr1 and arr2 to solve the result equation and print out the result like this:

```
arr1   arr2    Result
0       0        0
1       1        3
2       0        4
```

and so on.. but not all the combinations are used when I try this approach. What should I do to get all the possible combinations?

Answer (score 1):

Matlab has meshgrid function to eliminate loops for this purpose, for example

```
>> a1=[1:4];
>> a2=[0:3];
>> [x1,x2]=meshgrid(a1,a2);
>> r=x1.*x2+x1.^2+x2.^2;
```

or to use square once

```
>> r1=(x1+x2).^2-x1.*x2;
```

**UPDATE:** for your case you use 0:15 values, using them will result with

```
>> a1=[0:15];a2=[0:15];
>> [x1,x2]=meshgrid(a1,a2);
>> r=-x1.*x2+(x1+x2).^2;
>> size(r)

ans =

    16    16
```

**UPDATE 2** Note that your method doesn't create all pairs, for example (0,0) or (1,1) won't be there also only of one of the (x,y) (y,x) pairs will be there for x!=y values.  Other than double loops the preferred approach is what I proposed.  You can gather the results in a matrix in the form you want easily as well

```
>> n=size(r,1);
>> R=[reshape(x1,1,n*n); reshape(x2,1,n*n); reshape(r,1,n*n)]'
R =
     0     0     0
     0     1     1
     0     2     4
     0     3     9
     0     4    16
     0     5    25
     0     6    36
     0     7    49
     ...
    15     6   351
    15     7   379
    15     8   409
    15     9   441
    15    10   475
    15    11   511
    15    12   549
    15    13   589
    15    14   631
    15    15   675
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but this doesnt seem to work the way I want it to. It gives an output "1x4 double"

Comment: what are your input vectors?  Did you try the example I posted.  It should give you 4x4 matrix, the cross product of two inputs of size 4.

Comment: I tried with the example you gave me but still returns "1x4 double" . My input vectors are arr1 = A(:,1) and arr2 = A(:,2) (the code I have posted)

Comment: please copy/paste the code, it should be 16x16 as shown.  Cannot be one dimensional.

Comment: as i said at my post, these values should be placed in a table and give me output R for each combination. For example x1=5 |  x2= 1 | R = 31 , x1 = 0 | x2 = 3 | R= 9  etc..